# Como mudar a cor da pipe no NETBEANS?

Tags: java, netbeans

Eu estava mudando as cores do editor do NETBEANS , só que eu não consegui mudar a cor da pipe (a barra que aparece quando você vai escrever algo). Vocês podem me ajudar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, tente Ferramentas/
Opções/
Fontes e Cores/
Aba Realce/
Cor do Cursor/
E é isso aí, só mudar para uma cor que contraste com o fundo da sua tela

Comment: Opa , obrigado pela ajuda , resolveu bastante coisa .